How to install mysql-connector-python-8.4.0.zip it does not have setup.py
How to install mysql-connector-python-8.4.0.zip it does not have setup.py. Checked also: mysql-connector-python-8.4.0.tar.gz
Tried:
.\pip3.exe install mysql-connector-python-8.4.0.zip --upgrade
.\pip3.12.exe install mysql-connector-python-8.4.0.tar.gz
C:\Python312\Scripts\pip3.12.exe install setup.py
and much more but not working and giving an error. Looks for Windows .msi has been stopped too.
